# C++ std::thread and std::mutex app crashing (Abnormal Program Termination)

Tags: multithreading, crash, mutex, c++builder, vcl

I have a C++Builder VCL DLL project, and a timer on my Form. The timer calls a function, and that function creates a new `std::thread` (detached), and the `thread_function` calls other functions and does some things with global variables.

The problem is that the program crashes with an error saying "Abnormal Program Termination". Before I used the `std::thread` (I was calling functions directly), it was working well, but the GUI was hanging. Now, I'm using `std::thread`, but the program is crashing. I'm not sure, but maybe the global variables are causing this problem?

Basically, my code looks like this:

Form1.h

```
typedef struct{
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int z=0;
    int k=0;
    int j=0;
}nodeData;

std::vector<nodeData> nodeDataList;
//defined here because im using this on Form2 too
//pushing elements in Form1_Create event
```

Form1.cpp

```
int a=0;
int b=0;
AnsiString c;

bool ProcessNodeX(){
    c="processing x..";
    for (int i=0; i < Form1->ListBox1->Items->Count; i++) {
        if (a<12){b++;}
        if (Form1->nodeDataList.at(i).x>24){b++;}
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k=15
    }
    Form1->Timer1->Interval=1000;
    return true;
}

bool ProcessNodeY(){
    c="processing y..";
    for (int i=0; i < Form1->ListBox1->Items->Count; i++) {
        if (a<6){b++; Form1->Timer1->Interval=1500;}
        if (Form1->nodeDataList.at(i).y>12){b++;}
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k=20
    }
    return true;
}

bool ProcessNodeZ(){
    c="processing z..";
    for (int i=0; i < Form1->ListBox1->Items->Count; i++) {
        if (a<18){b++; Form1->Timer1->Interval=3000;}
        if (Form1->nodeDataList.at(i).z>16){b++;}
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k=30
    }
    return true;
}

void RelocateNodes(){
    int _local_val=0;
    if (ProcessNodeX()){_local_val++}
    if (ProcessNodeY()){_local_val++}
    if (ProcessNodeZ()){_local_val++}

    a++;
    if(b<a){
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k=15;
        Form1->Timer1->Enabled=true;
        return;
    }
    else{
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k=30;
        Form1->Timer1->Enabled=true;
        return;
    }

    if(Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k<20){
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).l=50;
        Form1->Timer1->Enabled=true;
        return;
    }

    Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).l=99;
    Form1->Timer1->Enabled=true;
    return;
}

void LaunchRelocate(){
    std::thread rlc(RelocateNodes);
    rlc.detach();
}

Timer1_Event(TObject *Sender){
    Form1->Timer1->Enabled=false;
    LaunchRelocate();
}
```

Then I tried to use a mutex/lock, like this:

Form1.h

```
typedef struct{
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int z=0;
    int k=0;
    int j=0;
}nodeData;

std::vector<nodeData> nodeDataList;
```

Form1.cpp

```
int a=0;
int b=0;
AnsiString c;
std::mutex psrMutex;

bool ProcessNodeX(){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(psrMutex);
    c="processing x..";
    for (int i=0; i < Form1->ListBox1->Items->Count; i++) {
        if (a<12){b++;}
        if (Form1->nodeDataList.at(i).x>24){b++;}
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k=15
    }
    Form1->Timer1->Interval=1000;
    return true;
}

bool ProcessNodeY(){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(psrMutex);
    c="processing y..";
    for (int i=0; i < Form1->ListBox1->Items->Count; i++) {
        if (a<6){b++; Form1->Timer1->Interval=1500;}
        if (Form1->nodeDataList.at(i).y>12){b++;}
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k=20
    }
    return true;
}

bool ProcessNodeZ(){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(psrMutex);
    c="processing z..";
    for (int i=0; i < Form1->ListBox1->Items->Count; i++) {
        if (a<18){b++; Form1->Timer1->Interval=3000;}
        if (Form1->nodeDataList.at(i).z>16){b++;}
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k=30
    }
    return true;
}

void RelocateNodes(){
    int _local_val=0;
    if (ProcessNodeX()){_local_val++}
    if (ProcessNodeY()){_local_val++}
    if (ProcessNodeZ()){_local_val++}

    psrMutex.lock();
    a++;
    if(b<a){
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k=15;
        Form1->Timer1->Enabled=true;
        psrMutex.unlock();
        return;
    }
    else{
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k=30;
        Form1->Timer1->Enabled=true;
        psrMutex.unlock();
        return;
    }

    if(Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k<20){
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).l=50;
        Form1->Timer1->Enabled=true;
        psrMutex.unlock();
        return;
    }

    Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).l=99;
    Form1->Timer1->Enabled=true;
    psrMutex.unlock();
    return;
}

void LaunchRelocate(){
    std::thread rlc(RelocateNodes);
    rlc.detach();
}

Timer1_Event(TObject *Sender){
    Form1->Timer1->Enabled=false;
    LaunchRelocate();
}
```

I'm not sure, did I use `mutex` the right way?  It is still crashing randomly (sometimes it crashes immediately when I start the timer, and sometimes it works for like 5-10 minutes). The default timer interval is 2000ms.

Comment: Nowhere in the code shown do you actually add elements to `nodeDataList`. Far as I can tell, it's an empty vector, and `nodeDataList.at(anything)` throws an exception that you don't handle.

Comment: Oh sorry i just forget to say that. Im pushing elements to vector in Form_Create event actually.

Answer (score 0):

The global variables are not causing your crashes. But, they will likely cause other problems if you don't protect them from being accessed by multiple threads at the same time.

More importantly, your `std::thread` code is accessing your VCL UI controls directly, but the VCL is NOT thread-safe! That can and likely will cause some major headaches. You MUST *synchronize* with the main UI thread whenever a worker thread wants to access the UI.  Using a `std::mutex` can protect your `nodeDataList` vector, but you cannot use a `std::mutex` to protect access to your UI, since the main thread does not use the `std::mutex` while managing the UI.

Try something more like this instead:

Form1.h

```
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
...
public:
    ...
    struct nodeData{
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int j = 0;
    };

    std::vector<nodeData> nodeDataList;
    std::mutex psrMutex;
    ...
};
```

Form1.cpp

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
AnsiString c;

bool ProcessNodeX(){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(Form1->psrMutex);
    c = "processing x..";
    int count /* = Form1->nodeDataList.size() */;
    TThread::Synchronize(nullptr, [&](){ count = Form1->ListBox1->Items->Count; });
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if (a < 12){ ++b; }
        if (Form1->nodeDataList.at(i).x > 24){ ++b; }
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k = 15;
    }
    TThread::Queue(nullptr, [](){ Form1->Timer1->Interval = 1000; });
    return true;
}

bool ProcessNodeY(){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(Form1->psrMutex);
    c = "processing y..";
    int count /* = Form1->ListBox1->Items->Count */;
    TThread::Synchronize(nullptr, [&](){ count = Form1->ListBox1->Items->Count; });
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if (a < 6){
            ++b;
            TThread::Queue(nullptr, [](){ Form1->Timer1->Interval = 1500; });
        }
        if (Form1->nodeDataList.at(i).y > 12){ ++b; }
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k = 20;
    }
    return true;
}

bool ProcessNodeZ(){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(Form1->psrMutex);
    c = "processing z..";
    int count /* = Form1->ListBox1->Items->Count */;
    TThread::Synchronize(nullptr, [&](){ count = Form1->ListBox1->Items->Count; });
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if (a < 18){
            ++b;
            TThread::Queue(nullptr, [](){ Form1->Timer1->Interval = 3000; });
        }
        if (Form1->nodeDataList.at(i).z > 16){ ++b; }
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k = 30;
    }
    return true;
}

void RelocateNodes(){
    int _local_val = 0;
    if (ProcessNodeX()){ ++_local_val; }
    if (ProcessNodeY()){ ++_local_val; }
    if (ProcessNodeZ()){ ++_local_val; }

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(Form1->psrMutex);
    ++a;
    if (b < a){
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k = 15;
        TThread::Queue(nullptr, [](){ Form1->Timer1->Enabled = true; });
        return;
    }
    else{
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k = 30;
        TThread::Queue(nullptr, [](){ Form1->Timer1->Enabled = true; });
        return;
    }

    // note: the following code is never reached,
    // since all code branches above are return'ing!

    if (Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).k < 20){
        Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).l = 50;
        TThread::Queue(nullptr, [](){ Form1->Timer1->Enabled = true; });
        return;
    }

    Form1->nodeDataList.at(0).l = 99;
    TThread::Queue(nullptr, [](){ Form1->Timer1->Enabled = true; });
}

void LaunchRelocate(){
    std::thread rlc(RelocateNodes);
    rlc.detach();
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1_Event(TObject *Sender){
    Timer1->Enabled = false;
    LaunchRelocate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I'll try that way like you said. (And thanks for explaining the UI-Thread situation)

Comment: And let me ask you something else, im accessing Form1's ui elements and nodeDataList on Form2 (reading and setting it) should i use Synchronize/Queue in there too?

Comment: `nodeDataList` is protected by a `mutex`, that is sufficient for it. But, does Form2 use a worker thread, too? All worker threads must synchronize with the main thread to access the UI.

Comment: I tried synchronize(), but this time the thread is not doing the job as expected(actually does nothing). I think the problem is that the project is of the dll type. I did some research and found some information about "CheckSynchronize". They wrote that this function should be called after Synchronize(). I tried calling this function directly in the DLL MainThread, but it didn't work. I then exported this function in the DLL and tried calling this function on the EXE where the DLL was running, but no matter how much I tried, I still couldn't get a result :(

Comment: @RetrobyteGames a DLL doesn't have a main thread, it just runs in whatever thread is calling into it. Please edit your question to show the latest code you are having trouble with. Please show the timer, the DLL definitions, Form1 and Form2 calling the DLL, everything that is relevant to providing a [mcve] to demonstrate the crash in action.